# Attaching MS Word, Excel and pdf files in Email

Tags: java, email, email-attachments, attachment

Below is the code I have for sending email which works great.

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package myWorkingFiles;

import org.apache.commons.mail.*;

/*
*
* @author xyz
*/
public class GmailEmailWorking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myEmailId = "myEmailId@gmail.com";
        String myPassword = "myPassword";
        String senderId = "senderId@yahoo.co.in";
        try {
            Email email = new SimpleEmail();
            email.setSmtpPort(587);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(myEmailId, myPassword));
            email.setDebug(true);
            email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
            email.setFrom(myEmailId);
            email.setSubject("Hi");
            email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
            email.addTo(senderId);
            email.setTLS(true);
            email.send();
            System.out.println("Mail sent!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to send email with attachement as oppose to plain email as shown above.

Please let me know what changes I will need to do? I believe its easy, but sadly Mr. Google is also not helping me.

I have found some links but they are not useful.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search landed me with this .. 
http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html

Are u trying to search for something different??